# Return move as well by changing this pseudocode

Tags: javascript, python, c, pseudocode, alpha-beta-pruning

Is there a way of rewriting this modified pseudocode so that it returns a move as well as a score?  Found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning#frbanner3). This is the `Alpha-Beta` algorithm that is an optimised version of the `Minimax` algorithm, both of which are used to find the optimal move in perfect information games, like `Tic-Tac-Toe`.

```
function alphabeta(node, α, β, maximizingPlayer)
      if node is a terminal node
          return the value of node
      if maximizingPlayer
          v = -∞
          for each child of node
              v = max(v, alphabeta(child, α, β, FALSE))
              α = max(α, v)
              if β ≤ α
                  break
          return v
      else
          v = ∞
          for each child of node
             v = min(v, alphabeta(child, α, β, TRUE))
              β = min(β, v)
              if β ≤ α
                  break 
          return v
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the Maximizing Part b/c both are similar

```
function alphabeta(node, a, b, maximizingPlayer)
    if node is a terminal node
         return valueOfNode, None
    if maximizingPlayer
        v = -∞
        for each move in node.possible_moves()
            child = play(move, TRUE) #True / False respresents if it should make an "x" or an "o" on the board
            temp_max, _ = alphabeta(child, a, b, FALSE) # "_" means disregard the value
            if temp_max > v:
                v = temp_max
                best_move = move
            a = max(a, v)
            if b <= a:
                break
        return v, best_move
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimize is really similar to maximize so will just do one part:

```
  function alphabeta(node, α, β, maximizingPlayer)
        if node is a terminal node
            return { value: value of node, node : node}
        if maximizingPlayer
            v = -∞
            bestNode = None
            for each child of node
                localMax = alphabeta(child, α, β, FALSE)
                if localMax.value > v
                    v = localMax.value
                    bestNode = localMax.node

                α = max(α, v)
                if β ≤ α
                    break
            return {value : v, node: bestNode}
```

Comment: @PAS sure! I don´t usually do pseudo code so wasn´t sure of correct sintax for null and returning tuple

Comment: @PAS isn´t the move the node?

Comment: No. The node typically is a class, with many characteristics. See:https://github.com/retep-mathwizard/pyai/blob/master/ttt/gamestate.py, this is what a node would typically contains

Comment: @PAS in that case isn´t it better to return the node, as it provides more information and you can get the move out of that?

Comment: Yeah, I changed it back

Comment: I realized that this won't work :( because the `node` doesn't contain the score, and there is no good way of passing the move along.

Comment: @Pas isn´t value the score? Where is the move info located?